# database created with access 2007 is not accessible by program in 2013

Tags: c#

I have created a database with MS Access 2007 and created a windows application that will use the database.It is working fine in all systems having MS Access Version 2007
But when I have installed the application in a System having MS Access 2013 version ,the application cannot getting connection to the database.Is there any solution?

Comment: Are you installing the application on the same computer or a different one?
if so, you probably haven't done the connection string correctly.

Comment: Installing on different conputer

Comment: think like this, how can the other computer have access to the database on the first computer?

Comment: the database is copied to the computer and trying to connect the database locally not through any network

Comment: While installing the setup the database will be copied to the local system C drive

Comment: that will be because of the location.
The location of the connection string will more than likely be different to the one that you are assigned it to in the first place. eg 1st C:\users\foo\documents\ 2nd C:\users\bar\documents\